# Array Sorting getting error

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
class arr{
//array sorting to find maximum value
public static void main(String[]args){
    int[] array={1,6,4,5,2};
    int n;
    int i,j;
    for( i=0;i<(array.length*2);i++){
        for( j=0;j<array.length;j++){
            if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
                array[j]=array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=array[j];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(array[array.length]);
}
```

}

>
    Can anyone tell me why i am getting runtime error and this sorting method will work or not?

> 

Comment: If you are getting runtime error, then this sorting method will not work.

Comment: @apomene  what are the corrections i can have in this code?

Comment: Well... what's your runtime error?

Comment: I assume you're getting an array out of bounds exception due to the array[j+1] call, given that that element doesn't exist when j = array.length - 1. You're trying to access an element outside the array's bounds with that call. Change your for loop to j < array.length - 1 and it will prevent the exception. You may have to fiddle with your code to get it working better at the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont reinvent the wheel..,  you are able to use arrays, so then use the array help class too...
:-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int[] array = { 1, 6, 4, 5, 2 };
    System.out.println("Array before sort " + Arrays.toString(array));
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println("Array before sort " + Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will likely have an `indexOutOfbounds` exception because your second loop:

```
for( j=0;j<array.length;j++){
        if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
            array[j]=array[j+1];
            array[j+1]=array[j];
        }
}
```

`J` loops through teh array then you attempt to index the array at `J + 1` which on the last element in the array would push it out of bounds thus throwing an `outOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

```
for( j=0;j<array.length;j++){
  if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
               array[j]=array[j+1];
               array[j+1]=array[j];
           }
 }
```

1. Since array.length = 5 and j < array.length, the value array[j+1] in the last round of the inner loop cause array out of bound exception.
2. The swap needs another variable to hold array[j] before changing it.

e.g:

```
int x;

    for( j=0;j<array.length - 1;j++){

      if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
                    x = array[j];
                    array[j]=array[j+1];
                   array[j+1]=x;
               }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The bubble sort algorithm can be implemented as follows

```
 public static void sort(int[] arr){

        int len = arr.length;

        int k = 0;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < len-1; j++){
        for(int i= 0+k; i < len-1; i += 2){

            if(arr[i] <= arr[i+1])
                continue;
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = tmp;
        }
        k++;

        if ( k % 2 == 0)
            k = 0;
    } }
```

The inner loop must alternately start at indexes 0 and 1 so as not to always swap the same pairs (k variable).

The others have already pointed out why you're getting an exception.